# ListPlot from DataSet

Tags: plotting, dataset

Let's say that I have the following Dataset:

```
ds = Dataset[
   AssociationThread[{"A", "B"}, #] & /@ {{Range[10], 
      Sin[#] & /@ Range[10]}, {Range[10], 
      Cos[#] & /@ Range[10]}, {Range[10], Tan[#] & /@ Range[10]}}];
```

In column B, you have in each row respectively: `Sin`, `Cos` and `Tan` of the values that are in the same row of A.

How can do a ListPlot of those three rows in the most convenient way ?

Comment: That's... a really weird format. Do you actually get a `Dataset[]` shaped like this in your actual problem?

Comment: Can you consider re-formatting, eg to this? `Range[10] // 
  Map[<|"A" -> #, "B" -> Cos[#], "C" -> Sin[#], 
     "D" -> Tan[#]|> &] // Dataset` . Then you can plot pairs like: `ds2[All, {"A", "B"} /* Values] // ListPlot`

Comment: @J.M. I agree. The reason: I am acquiring experimental data of a reflection spectrum of different samples. Each sample is specified by a set of parameters, like size, thickness etc. -> one number for each parameter. For each of those samples, I record the "wavelength" and the "reflection" -> those two are lists, for the wavelength from 400nm to 800nm and for the reflection you have a value between 0 and 1 depending on your wavelength. So basically I have a table where in the first columns there is only one number, and in the last two, there are lists.

Comment: @J.M. I figured a way how to change the dataset structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each row represents a list with `x` values (key `A`) and `y` values (key `B`), I would do something like this to get all data in 1 plot:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{#A, #B}] & /@ ds]
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot !